# How can I save an ENV VAR on Linux Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, terminal, environment-variables

I typed on my terminal the following command :
`export BACKEND_URL="<confidential>"`
. Apparently it was working, but when I turned off my computer and turned on again, I realized that this env var named **BACKEND_URL** It was not saved anymore. Why this happened ?

Comment: Search is your friend, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

This question would better fit the [Unix&Linux StackExchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) than this web site.

However:

By typing "`BACKEND_URL="<confidential>"`" you set a variable which is valid for the currently running shell (terminal window) only.

If you close the terminal window, the variable is gone. The variable is also not valid for programs started from that terminal window.

If you add `export` (as you did), the variable is also valid for programs started from that terminal window.

However, still it is not valid for other terminal windows and if you close the teminal window, it will be gone.

When using one of the standard shells, you can add variables to the `.profile` file in your home directory.

When you are using `bash`, you can also add variables to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks for anwering me. Now i know hot to procede!